# NetSuite Script Online Form Creating Case Record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Hello i am trying to create a new record using a custom script on an online form. I need to use script as i want the created record to follow an internal workflow. According to this article it has to be done using script (https://netsuitehub.com/forums/topic/workflow-not-working-on-online-form/)

I have written the following code but i get the following error. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
define(["N/record"], function (r) { 
/** 
 * 
 * @NApiVersion 2.x 
 * @NModuleScope Public 
 * @NScriptType ClientScript 
 */ 
var exports = {}; 
function saveRecord(context) { 

    var jsonObj = {};

    jsonObj.companyName = document.getElementById("companyname").value ;
    jsonObj.firstName = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    jsonObj.lastName = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    jsonObj.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    jsonObj.title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    jsonObj.caseType = document.getElementById("category").value;
    jsonObj.caseCategory = document.getElementById("custevent_case_category").value;
    jsonObj.status = document.getElementById("status").value;
    jsonObj.origin = document.getElementById("origin").value;
    jsonObj.product = document.getElementById("custevent_external_productcrmfield").value;
    jsonObj.module = document.getElementById("custevent_external_modulecrmfield").value;
    jsonObj.message = document.getElementById("incomingmessage").value;

    console.log(jsonObj);
    try{
        var record = r.create({
            type: r.Type.CASE,
            isDynamic: false,
            defaultValues: null
        }).setValue({
            fieldId: "companyname",
            value:jsonObj.companyName,
        }).setValue({
            fieldId: "title",
            value: jsonObj.title
        }).setValue({
            fieldId: "status",
            value: jsonObj.status
        }).setValue({
            fieldId: "custevent_case_category",
            value: jsonObj.caseCategory
        }).setValue({
            fieldId: "profile",
            value : "1"
        }).save({
            enableSourcing: true,
            ignoreMandatoryFields: false
        });
        //log.debug('new record', record);
    }catch(error){
        console.log('error',error);
    }

} 
exports.saveRecord = saveRecord; 
return exports;
```

});

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Solution was that type.CASE had to be type.SUPPORT_CASE